# Responsive images and text transitions

Tags: css, responsive-design, typography

How can i make a responsive image that fits 100% width and 100% height on both iphone and desktops. I mean like this -
http://themeforest.unitedthemes.com/wpversions/brooklyn/elegant/
It is ok if it sacrifices a little of the image from either side but it should maintain the aspect ratio and it should fit the entire screen
i have tried to do it but to no avail

And i have noticed the transitions and the text on the images at the top. how do we do that.

Here is my code so far

HTML

```
<div id="body">
    <div>
        <img src="1.jpg" class="image" />
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.image {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    max - width: 100 % ;
    max - height: 100 % ;
    width: auto;
}
```

But here the thing is that the image isnt fit to the height and width of the screen. How do I achieve the aforementioned 100% width and height like in the link I gave.

Comment: Welcome to SO, Unfortunately, questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results. See also: Stack Overflow question checklist.

Comment: Ok.. wait. let me provide my code

Comment: There, now i have provided my code, i am new here, so i didnt know anything. thanks man

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using images to achieve this use a background image and set the following css :

```
#body{
  background-image:url(yourimgurl);
  background-position:50% 50%;
  background-size:cover;
}
```

It will cause your image to span the entire container and trim a bit off the sides when it's smaller.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/W6e24/)

Comment: I tried that and the background image isnt appearing. I am just a beginner in HTML and CSS and this is my first real website.
here is my code now

HTML
    <div id="body">
    </div>

CSS
    #body{
    bacgkround-image:url('Image.jpg');
    background-position:50% 50%;
    background-size:cover;
    }

Comment: @user3219918 you need to set a width and a height to #body as well

Comment: It still is not working.
#body{
  bacgkround-image:url('Image.jpg');
  background-position:50% 50%;
  background-size:cover;
  height:700px;
  width:1000px;
}

Comment: Background is spelt incorrectly in the code example above and in your response.

Comment: @TomMaton Cheers on grabbing the typo ^^

Comment: Thanks for the fiddle. Works like a charm. Patsy Issa, you are the man.

Comment: @user3219918 Np ^^ sorry abt the typo, feel free to accept the answer if it solved your problem

Comment: Done mate. You certainly have been helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do this:

1. set height, width 100% to the `<body>`
2. set height, width 100% to `.image`
3. add your background-image
4. add background-size: 100% (background-size 100% will cover the whole space)

Pen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/aHiBn

Gist: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/8935834